# How to copy text with accents from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, macos, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy text from Eclipse to Excel, but letters with accents do not display well.

I'm working on a mac. All my files in Eclipse are encoded in UTF8.

It seems to be a problem with Eclipse.
When I copy text from Eclipse to wherever, letters with accents do not display well.

The only solution I found so far is not to copy the text directly from Eclipse but instead to open the file with the text I want to copy with another editor such as TextEdit for copying.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show your copy & paste code?

Comment: "Sorry I forgot to mention I'm working on a mac" - OK, I have no idea how to transfer data into Mac Excel. You're likely to have to have to specify the character encoding, though, or use a separate Unicode interface. And my comment about "using the clipboard to transfer data isn't friendly to your users" applies to the Mac too...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with Eclipse.

When I copy text from Eclipse to wherever, letters with accents do not display well.

The only solution I found so far is not to copy the text directly from Eclipse but instead to open the file with the text I want to copy with another editor such as TextEdit.